# How Can I Skip Database file or Model file while loading Main page in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am new in codeigniter, please don't give negative rate. I have created a database and users table model file for login register project. the model code is here,

```
  <?php

    class setup_model extends CI_Model

    {

        public function __construct() {

        }

        public function createDatabase()

        {

            $this->load->dbforge();


           if ($this->dbforge->create_database('loginproject5'))

           $this->db->query('use loginproject5');


            $fields = array(

                'user_id' => array(

                    'type' => 'int',
                    'constraint' => 11,
                    'unsigned' => true,
                    'auto_increment' => true

                ),
                'username' => array(

                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'constraint' => 30,

                ),

                'password' => array(

                 'type' => 'varchar',
                    'constraint' => 30,


                ),

                'email' => array(

                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'constraint' => 50,
                )


            );


             $this -> dbforge -> add_field($fields);

             $this -> dbforge -> add_key('user_id', true);

             $this -> dbforge -> create_table('users');


             echo "Setup Done Succesfully";


        }


    }
```

I want to setup database first from project folder. so i have set this. now while loading the main file firstly database get set. but while loading second time it gives error, because database already set. now i want to skip database setup second time while loading main page. how to set condition to get rid of it or how to skip it. my controller code is here

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this-> home();
    }


  public function home () 

{

 $data['title'] = 'This is title';


 $data['page_header'] = "Login Register Program";

 $this -> load -> model('setup_model');

$this -> setup_model -> createDatabase();

 $this -> load -> view('view_home', $data);


}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your createDatabase() function in Model,
wrap everything inside if condition as shown in code sample below . This create_database() will check whether your database exist or not and execute the subsequent code.You are just missing that.

```
if ($this->dbforge->create_database('loginproject5')) 
{
....
}
```

## EDIT

Since, it is not working as expected, you could check if db exist or not

```
 public function createDatabase()
 {
 $this->load->dbutil();
 $this->load->dbforge();
 if (!$this->dbutil->database_exists('loginproject5'))
 {
   your code...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check database connection first

```
    if( $this->load->database() === FALSE ){//no database //your code here//}
else{
redirect('welcome');
}
```

Comment: i have check this code same thing showing, database exit's error

Comment: where have to give this code?, i am getting still error

Comment: Can't create database 'loginproject5'; database exists